# foreach loop List performance difference

Tags: c#, performance, foreach, lambda

While working on a project I ran into the following piece of code, which raised a performance flag.

```
foreach (var sample in List.Where(x => !x.Value.Equals("Not Reviewed")))
{
    //do other work here
    count++;
}
```

I decided to run a couple of quick tests comparing the original loop to the following loop:

```
foreach (var sample in List)
{
    if (!sample.Value.Equals("Not Reviewed"))
    {
        //do other work here
        count++;
    }
}
```

and threw this loop in too to see what happens:

```
var tempList = List.Where(x => !x.Value.Equals("Not Reviewed"));
foreach (var sample in tempList)
{
    //do other work here
    count++;
}
```

I also populated the original list 3 different ways: 50-50 (so 50% of values where "Not Reviewed" and the rest other), 10-90 and 90-10. These are my results, the first and last loops
are mostly the same but the second one is much faster, especially on 10-90 case. Why exactly? I always thought `Lambda` had good performance.

***EDIT***

The `count++` is not actually what's inside the loop, I just added that here for demonstration purposes, I guess I should've used "//do something here"

[image: Performance Results]

***EDIT 2***

Results running each one 1000 times:
[image: Performance Results 1000 times]

Comment: It'd be interesting to see how `List.Where(x => !x.Value.Equals("Not Reviewed")).Count()` performs compared to those.

Comment: @MikePrecup: Or even better, `List.Count(x => !x.Value.Equals("Not Reviewed"))`

Comment: Have you made sure you didn't make any of these [Performance Benchmark Mistakes](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one)?

Comment: I'd be surprised if #1 and #3 don't compile to the exact same thing...

Comment: @AustinSalonen I think they are not, why else would their performance be different?

Comment: 1 ms is not significant enough here to be _different_ (especially on single runs)...

Comment: @SOfanatic: Because of noise in benchmarking, basically. You can see that you're not getting the exact same results every run anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought the difference in all three cases was because of the data distribution (50% "Not Reviewed", 10% "Not Reviewed", and 90% "Not Reviewed")

Comment: @SOfanatic:  Run each one a 1000 times and report the distributions -- you're not working with enough data points to make a good assessment.

Comment: @SOfanatic: Ah, forgot that - but try running it many times on the same data set and I'm sure you'll see the results vary over time.

Comment: @AustinSalonen ok I added the results for 1000 times and it seems to produce the same results.

Comment: @SOfanatic: It doesn't help that apparently you haven't presented the results in the same order both times. I suspect the bottom screenshot of the second set is equivalent to the *middle* screenshot in the first set.

Comment: @JonSkeet it's the same order. The 1st in both is 50-50, 2nd is 10-90 ( not reviewed/review) and 90-10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, there's a small amount of extra indirection - both for the test via a delegate, and for the iterating part. Given just how little work is being done per iteration, that extra indirection is relatively expensive.

That's neither surprising nor worrying, in my view. It's the kind of micro-optimization you can easily perform *if* you're in the rare situation of it being significant in your real-world application. In my experience it's pretty rare for this sort of loop to be a significant bottleneck in the app. The normal approach should be:

- Define performance requirements
- Implement the functional requirements in the clearest, simplest way you can
- Measure your performance against the requirements
- If performance is found wanting, investigate why and only move away from clarity as little as you can, getting the biggest "bang for buck" that you can
- Repeat until you're done

Responding to an edit:

> The count++ is not actually what's inside the loop, I just added that here for demonstration purposes, I guess I should've used "//do something here"

Well that's the important bit - the more work that is done there, the less significant anything else will be. Just counting is pretty darned fast, so I'd expect to see a large discrepancy. Do any amount of real work, and the difference will be smaller.